# go back one tab index

Tags: c#, textbox, tabs, keyboard

probably a simple one, have a dozen textboxes that each contain one character. i'm try to process the delete key to clear the current text in the current textbox, then i want it to decrement the tab index by go and go back to edit the previous textbox. i don't know how to reference the current textbox's tab index and go back one. to go to the next one i'm merely performing a send key for 'TAB'.

in my keyprocess function i have:

```
//DEL goes back one text box and clears it
            if (keyData == (Keys.Delete))
            {
                //Clear textbox
                //Go back one textbox to edit
                return true;
            }
```

again once i finished editing a text box i am sending:

```
 SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

maybe there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Windows Form? WCF? Silverlight? Web Forms?

Comment: Have you tried `{SHIFT}{TAB}`? It does feel like a bit of a hack though. There must be better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the previous `TextBox` with the [GetNextControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getnextcontrol.aspx) method:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
{
    var textBox = ((TextBox) sender);
    textBox.Text = string.Empty;

    var previous = textBox.Parent.GetNextControl(textBox, false);
    if (previous != null)
        previous.Focus();

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Or as @Mr Lister suggested you can send the SHIFT+TAB key combination with:
 `SendKeys.Send("+{TAB}");` but it's a little hacky solution.

Comment: yes the "hack" seems little better. for your solution, but key process function does not define a sender or "e"....`protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {}`

Comment: It was not clear form your question that you are using `ProcessCmdKey`. Are there any special reason to use it? Because from what you've described subscribing on `KeyDown` with the same handler on each `TextBox` would also do the trick.